# Why won't my NSColor extension see a CGColor?

Tags: swift, extension-methods, swift-extensions, nscolor, cgcolor

This baffles me... I'm trying to create a convenience initializer for `NSColor` which makes one out of a `CGColor`, but for some dang reason it just refuses to acknowledge that `CGColor` exists! I have imported `Cocoa`, and just for sanity I also imported `CoreGraphics` and even `CoreGraphics.CGColor` but still no luck!

[image: All the imports I should need, but CGColor is not found]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Cleaning and rebuilding doesn't help...

Comment: Why? `NSColor` already has an [`init(cgColor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/colorWithCGColor:)

Comment: @Hamish aw, dang... that wasn't showing up in my autocomplete for some reason. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said in the comments, 
`NSColor` has an `init(cgColor:)` initializer, that might
render your problem obsolete.

But since you are asking *why* it does not compile:
The reason is that `NSColor` has a `CGColor`
property, and that conflicts with the `CGColor` type.
As a workaround, one can use the `CGColorRef` alias:

```
extension NSColor {

    convenience init(_ cgColor: CGColorRef) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As  Eric Aya said, the problem does not exist with Xcode 8 beta 4. The reason is that the `NSColor` property was renamed to `cgColor`, and does not conflict with the `CGColor` type anymore,

Comment: I've also noticed that OP's code works in Xcode 8 b4. Apple seems to have fixed this compiler issue.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for all the knowledge!

Comment: @EricAya: Yes, the property was renamed to `cgColor` in Swift 3.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode is clearly misbehaving here. Workaround: use the complete type in the signature.

```
convenience init(_ cgColor: CoreGraphics.CGColor)
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer!

Comment: I think this solution is better than @MartinR's because it doesn't rely on the availability of a typealias, and thus is more general

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: I do not disagree, but the main point of my answer was to explain *why* the problem occurs. It is not a "misbehaving compiler" but conflicting definitions in the frameworks.

Comment: @MartinR To clarify, I like your answer more, because you give that backgorund explaination. However, I think EricAya's *solution* is better.